# How to generalize a variable on both sides of an equation in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have this goal

```
size (flatten (N t1 t2)) = size (N t1 t2)
```

`N` is a `bin` constructor, how can I replace `N t1 t2` in both sides by `t3 : bin`?

My hypothesis are

```
t1, t2 : bin
IHt1 : size (flatten t1) = size t1
IHt2 : size (flatten t2) = size t2
```

If I can rewrite `size (flatten (N t1 t2)) = size (N t1 t2)` as `size (flatten t3) = size t3` then I can apply my hypothesis to finish the proof.

Here is the full code

```
Require Import Nat.
Require Import Arith.

Inductive bin : Type :=
    L : bin
  | N : bin -> bin -> bin.

Fixpoint flatten_aux (t1 t2 : bin) : bin :=
  match t1 with
    L => N L t2
  | N t'1 t'2 => flatten_aux t'1  (flatten_aux t'2 t2)
  end.

Fixpoint flatten (t : bin) : bin :=
  match t with
    L => L
  | N t1 t2 => flatten_aux t1 (flatten t2)
  end.

Fixpoint size (t : bin) : nat :=
  match t with
    L => 1
  | N t1 t2 => 1 + size t1 + size t2
  end.


Lemma flatten_aux_size :
  forall t1 t2, size (flatten_aux t1 t2) =
    size t1 + size t2 + 1.
  induction t1.
  { intros t2.
    simpl.
    ring.
  }
  { intros t2; simpl.
    rewrite IHt1_1.
    rewrite IHt1_2.
    ring.
  }
Qed.

Lemma flatten_size : forall t, size (flatten t) = size t.
  induction t.
  { trivial.
  }
  { simpl.
    (* goal size (flatten (N t1 t2)) = size (N t1 t2) *)
```

In the end I use this solution

```
Lemma flatten_size : forall t, size (flatten t) = size t.
  induction t.
  { trivial.
  }
  { simpl.
    rewrite flatten_aux_size.
    rewrite <- IHt1.
    rewrite <- IHt2.
    rewrite Nat.add_comm.
    simpl.
    reflexivity.
  }
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you have `size (flatten t3) = size t3`? Your hypotheses are not universally quantified, `size (flatten t2) = size t2` holds for that particular `t2` (same with `t1`).
Without more details we cannot help you but I would expect that you rather show how `flatten` behaves when applied to `N t1 t2` in terms of `flatten t1` and `flatten t2` which would then help you conclude.

Comment: This explain why I couldn't use `rewrite .. with (t1 := N t1 t2). Thanks I will update the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

you did the right thing using `simpl` : it partially evaluates `size (flatten (N t1 t2))`  and `size (N t1 t2)`
so you can use your induction hypothesis.